# Prevent form data re-send in Code Igniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm a pretty new with the Code Igniter (as its my first framework I'm learning).

I got this in my controller:

```
   if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('account/register', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message'] = $this->lang->line('account_created');
        $this->register->insert_account();
        $this->load->view('account/register_success', $data);
    }
```

If form is validated successfully , it does just change the view, but it is still possible to hit the refresh button, and re-send the form data - its not a big problem for me since I'm checking if fields are unique, but would be better for me to prevent from re-sending the form data.

Normally in clean PHP I would use `header("Location: ...");` but I'm loading a view here, so it won't be possible to access it after redirection - isnt it?

Have you any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redirect to the same page but also use codeigniters flashdata in the session library.
On a form submit set the flashdata with a success message.
Redirect to the same page with the form and display the flashdata success message.
By redirecting the page is reloaded and prevents a refresh.

**controller**

Do this on form success

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("success", $strMessage);
redirect("account/register");
```

**view**

This will show a success message on the form page

```
if($this->session->flashdata("success") !== FALSE)
{
    echo "<div class=\"formSuccess\">" . $this->session->flashdata("success") . "</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ajax the view you need into a div. See what  I  mean? change the contents of the page but not the page itself.